# Issues with includes in QT

Tags: c++, qt, include, qmake

I have a basic issue with includes. My project structure looks like this:

```
myProject.pro
---directoryA
   directoryA.pri
   ---directoryA1
      firstHeader.h
      secondHeader.h
      secondHeader.cpp
main.cpp
```

This is how myProject.pro looks like (I have ony written lines which I though to be relevant)

**myProject.pro:**

```
include(directoryA/directoryA.pri)
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**directoryA.pri:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD

HEADERS += \
$$PWD/directoryA/firstHeader.h \
$$PWD/directoryA/secondHeader.h

SOURCES+= \
$$PWD/directoryA/secondHeader.cpp
```

Given this structure, a simple include that I want to do in secondHeader.h from firstHeader.h does not work:

firstHeader.h:

```
#define firstheaderVar 4
```

secondHeader.h:

```
#include "firstheader.h"
int secondHeaderVar = firstheaderVar;
```

Simply I can not include anything from the first one within second one. It always gives the '...' was not declared in this scope error.

I suspect this to be an error caused by my project directory structure but can not find an elegant way to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `firstheader.h` and `firstHeader.h` are the same file in `directoryA1`?

Comment: I think you made a typing error in your question @S.M.

Comment: If it would be an header files problem, compiler would be complain that it cannot find a header to include. But it looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot: **./**

try something like this:

```
#include "./firstheader.h"
```